# Sharing WPF-Dictionary from another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Ok, I busting my head on this for few hours now and still cannot find a solution.

first I shall explain the simple test case I created:
Solution

```
- ClassLibrary1
  - Dictionary1.xaml
- WpfApplication3
  - App.config
  - App.xaml
  - Dictionary2.xaml
  - MainWindows.xaml
```

**ClassLibrary1:**

That project has the required references to allow me to add wpf-dictionary:
PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, Systam.Xaml, windowsbase
(Along with all standard assemblies for any regular class library)

And this is `Dictionary1.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryBackgroundColor">#FF030010</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource PrimaryBackgroundColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**WpfApplication3:**

This project just display a button on a wpf-form.

`Dictionary2.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1.dll;component/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBackgroundBrush}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="aaa" Width="100" Height="40" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

That's all - very simple as you can see.
The only thing here is that dictionary2 need to use resource from dictionary1.

And so there are two ways to reference another assembly:

**Option 1:**
The class-library is a project in your solution and your WpfApplication adds reference to the class library project which is in the same solution. this is done via Add-Reference/Projects, And in that situation all works great.

**Option 2:**
The class-library is not your solution. (actually it can be like in my example)
however you add reference by adding reference to `ClassLibrary1.Dll` which resides either in your
`bin\debug` or `bin\release` folders.
In that situation a portal to hell is opened.
Dictionary2 complains it cannot find the resource 'PrimaryBackgroungBrush' and upon execution it crush
complaining it cannot find the dictionary1.xaml

Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
and the inner exception:
{"Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1.dll, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.":"ClassLibrary1.dll, Culture=neutral"}

The problem is that using option2 is essential as I want to share the same dictionary among other wpf projects without
having the ClassLibrary1 project as part of their solution.

Suggested way to reproduce:

1. Create a new solution in Visual studio for WPF application.
2. Add class library project to the solution.
3. In class libarary project, Add references to the following assemblies:   PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, Systam.Xaml, windowsbase
4. Add Wpf-Dictionary 'Dictionary1' to your class library project and copy the code. (you can copy one from the wpf project since it will not exist as an option in the add item from the class library)
5. Add Wpf-Dictionary 'Dictionary2' to your wpf application and copy the code.
6. Copy the code for MainWindow.

And now:

7. Add reference to class library (as project, from projects tab in add refernce dialog)
   Build everything - all should work.
8. Remove the refernce to class library. 
   Add reference to class library (as dll, from browse tab and find it in your classlibrary/bin/debug or release folder)
   Build everything - you will notice my problem.

Any solution to this problem?

**UPDATE 1**

I changed the line in dictionary2.xaml from:
  `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1.dll;component/Dictionary1.xaml"/>`

To:
  `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1;component/Dictionary1.xaml"/>`

And now the project compiles and execute without an error, However while in design time - the xaml view of `dictionary2` indicate that it cannot find the resource: 'PrimaryBackgroundBrush` and puts the ugly curly underline below it.
So its a progress - but i'm still not happy with that. 
Any ideas how to solve that?

**UPDATE 2**
As previously stated - everything compiles and execute now.
However what you see in the following picture annoys me,
I just want to be sure that others who added the class library as .Dll file and not as project 100% sure they don't get that problem which can be seen in the picture, meaning their xaml intellisense can recognize the resource during design time.
[image: the error I see]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You forgot to mention `WindowsBase` (as reference to class library project). Then there is no Wpf-Dictionary in class library "add item" dialog (for wpf application it's called `Resource Dictionary (WPF)`), can be solved by copying one from wpf application. Then everything compiles. Removing class library from solution and referencing dll - still works.

Comment: @Sinatr you sure you add a 2nd dictionary as I showed in the wpf project?
(also thanks I added the info you pointed out to the question body)

Comment: I too have tried to recreate your problem and have been unsuccessful. The dictionary declared in the program's project merges the DLL's dictionary, the resource in the DLL's dictionary can be referenced in the program project's dictionary, and that dictionary can in turn be successfully merged in the `Window`'s dictionary. The rendered element that depends on the resources is displayed correctly. Please double-check everything (including build settings for the dictionary files), simplify your example, and make sure you've included a good [mcve].

Comment: Ok, Last update - just to be 100% sure - you saying that after adding it as .dll (not project) you don't see the error I showing during design-time.

Comment: thinking.. maybe its a resharper thing?

Comment: Looking at update2, how would others know what they have to add merged dictionary to their xamls and use resources by keys from `Dictionary1.xaml`? That's not something you expect from dll. You may want to do something here, perhaps some method what has to be called to do that merging automatically (it can be called as xaml extension which has to be added to window/usercontrol). I've done theme manager like this and it seems to work during design time and run-time perfectly. Then it's easy to use for a user of dll.

Comment: @Sinatr I don't quite understand your point - and it seems important to me.. can you please explain better. it seems you found a flaw from architecture point of view? is it wrong to have a base dictionary (or theme) in general DLL and share it across many projects.. and from a project point of view to merge the base dictionary and base new styles upon it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine how documentation about that dll will looks like:

- > reference dll in the project
- > add this to resource dictionary in the project:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1.dll;component/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

- > add this to each window/usercontrol:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Which looks afwul.

How about making manager in your library which has to be referenced by each window/usercontrol  and it will do things automatically?

---

Here is a cut from theme manager I mentioned in comments (it does merging automatically), think about easy of use.

xaml (add this to each window/usercontrol which has to support theme switching in design/run time):

```
         local:Theme.Theme=""
```

cs (this part has to be a part of library):

```
public static class Theme
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThemeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Theme", typeof(string), typeof(Theme), new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
        {
            var theme = (string)e.NewValue;
            // in run-time set theme to specified during init
            if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(d))
                theme = _theme;
            var element = d as FrameworkElement;
            element.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(theme))
            {
                var uri = new Uri($"/MyPorject;component/Themes/{theme}.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                element.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = uri });
            }
        }));
    public static string GetTheme(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(ThemeProperty);
    public static void SetTheme(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(ThemeProperty, value);

    static string _theme = "Generic";

    static string[] _themes = new[]
    {
        "Test",
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Init themes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="theme">Theme to use</param>
    public static void Init(string theme)
    {
        if (_themes.Contains(theme))
            _theme = theme;
    }
}
```

P.S.: functionality is primitive (it is sufficient in my case), but should give you an idea.

Comment: first, thank you for that answer. I will look into it as deep as possible to see how this suggestion can help with the issue. second, the assumption is incorrect - I will not put in each `window/usercontrol` resources a merge dictionary - instead - i will put it in the app.xaml - I do wonder if that means that it still duplicate the dictionary per instance - I think it is not doing that.. for now +1 :)